# How to specify facilityId for a tileset in Azure IndoorMaps?

Tags: azure-maps

I've followed the Azure Indoor Maps Creator tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/tutorial-creator-indoor-maps) but used a python script from another repository [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCreator) to make it simpler to upload the map files. No PostMan required basically.

The sample wires up a `levelchanged` event handler and outputs the event data to console.  The event's data for `facilityId` is always `FCL13`.  I cannot find where this data is specified anywhere. Not in the python script, the sample data zipfile manifest.json, nor in the DWG files (with my limited ability to view those).

I assume I should be able to specify which facility I am uploading data for so would either expect the API calls to be provided this (from the python script), or it should be some metadata within the DWG files.

My intention was to upload more than one building's floor maps so need the facilityId to be configurable.  Having specific tilesets associated to different facilityIds allows me to know which facility had its level changed during a levelchanged event.

Where is the facilityId data specified for a specific map data upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Ids (facilityId, levelId, unitId, etc.) are generated when you [create a dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/tutorial-creator-indoor-maps#create-a-dataset). These Ids are not meant to be set manually.

It is possible to list facilityIds loaded in the map, along with their names, address info, etc. that was provided in manifest.json.

**Note:** It looks like the 'indoorTiles' source lacks the getShapes() method so a workaround is required to query the underlying mapbox.

```
map._getMap().querySourceFeatures('indoorTiles', {sourceLayer: 'Indoor facility'});
```

From Mapbox's documentation on [querySourceFeatures()](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#querysourcefeatures):

> Because features come from tiled vector data or GeoJSON data that is converted to tiles internally, feature geometries may be split or duplicated across tile boundaries and, as a result, features may appear multiple times in query results.

Comment: I'm not so sure in regards to facilityId @mbelt. I uploaded 2 dwg zips (the sample and another modified for different gps anchor so no geographic overlap).  These result in 2 different tileset ids, as expected.  If I do a test using each tilesetId separately, the levelchanged event that fires is always FCL13.  If this is generated as you say, I'd ask why is it always the same value, and why specifically "...13"?  Can I ask where you source the information for your answer please?

Comment: I tried using your getShape to look at the VectorTileSource and unfortunately the method is not defined on the source instance returned from 'indoorTiles'.  I put my code in a setTimeout too to be sure I'm getting a source instance for the indoorTiles Id, and even listed all the methods of this object.  No getShape defined.  I can only assume this is not a VectorTileSource, or the doco for that type is incorrect.

Comment: You're right. It looks like that source is not actually a 'VectorTileLayer' it's something else. It is possible, as a fallback, to go directly to the underlying mapbox to access the vector source.
`map._getMap().querySourceFeatures('indoorTiles', {sourceLayer: 'Indoor facility'})`

The GeoJSON Features returned by that will have the properties you are looking for.

Comment: Regarding '13', just an observation that the numeric portion of `id` in a data set appears to be unique across all features regardless of type. The facility must be the 13th feature processed when a dataset is built from a DWG conversion.